# MySql messaging system query fetch one message per conversation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this 3 tables:

```
messages:
id  conv    snd text    created
1   1   1   asdasd      2012-12-15 23:10:53
3   1   1   zzz         2013-01-18 12:37:44
4   1   1   ssss        2013-01-18 12:42:01


msg_status
id  msg user    status
1   1   1       mine
2   1   4       unread
3   3   1       mine
4   3   4       unread
5   4   1       mine
6   4   4       unread


conv_users
conv    user
1       1
1       4
2       1
2       4
2       5
```

This is a messaging system in my site, I have all ready to go except this small query,
that suppose to get all of the user conversation with the last message in the conversation.

That means, if user A had 2 conversations, and in conv1 has 10 messages, and in conv2 has only 2 messages, he will get two rows with: convId, messageId, messageText, messageDate etc.

But the problem is that that message should be the last one in each conversation.

This is my query I have done, but it doesnt work!

```
SELECT
  cu.conv,
  msg.snd,
  msg.text,
  mst.status,
  msg.created
FROM conv_users AS cu
  INNER JOIN messages AS msg
    ON cu.conv = msg.conv
  INNER JOIN msg_status AS mst
    ON msg.id = mst.msg
WHERE cu.user = 4
    AND mst.user = 4
ORDER BY msg.created DESC
```

if I add `GROUP BY cu.conv` it display the first message and not the last as I want.

Comment: Try having a read through some recent threads. This question is asked ooh every six or seven minutes.

Comment: I think you have a missing relationship in your table, look table `messages`, how will you know that a particular message is from conv `1,1` or from `1,4`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using derieved query with max

```
SELECT
  cu.conv,
  msg.snd,
  msg.text,
  mst.status,
  msg.created
FROM conv_users AS cu
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id), conv FROM messages GROUP BY conv )messages AS msg ON cu.conv = msg.conv
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) , msg FROM msg_status GROUP BY msg) AS mst ON msg.id = mst.msg 
WHERE cu.user = 4
    AND mst.user = 4
ORDER BY msg.created DESC
```